# Why are the results of glm() and lrm() inconsistent?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Through the sample code in lrm() function, I tested the function of glm() and lrm() , and the results are consistent, but when fitting my own logistic model, the results obtained by glm() and lrm() are inconsistent, why?

My code is as follows:

```
y <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor")
x <- c(2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 
5, 3, 3, 3, 4)
coef(glm(y ~ x, family = "binomial"))
coef(lrm(y ~ x))
```

The result were:

```r
> coef(glm(y ~ x, family = "binomial"))
(Intercept)           x 
  -62.50203    21.20021 
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
> coef(lrm(y ~ x))
Intercept         x 
-28.63253   9.91038
```

Comment: Where is function `lrm` coming from? Please always explicitly state any non-base R packages.

Comment: I'am sorry for didn't make it clear, lrm from the package `rms`.